# plot in red, green or blue levels

Tags: r

Is there a way to plot a matrix/image using the function `plot()` with red or green or blue levels, just like the color option `grey(level, alpha = NULL)`?

The grey levels range between 0(black) and 1(white).

I am looking for the same thing with RGB:

- Red levels would range between 0(red) and 1(white).
- Green levels would range between 0(green) and 1(white).
- Blue levels would range between 0(blue) and 1(white).

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you searching for [?colorRamp](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/colorRamp.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `colorRampPalette()` (replacing `"red"` with `"blue"` or `"green"` as desired):

```
 ## Matrix from ?image
 x <- y <- seq(-4*pi, 4*pi, len = 27)
 r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+"))

 ## Plot it using a palette of your choice
 image(z = z <- cos(r^2)*exp(-r/6), 
       col  = colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(64))
```

[image]